# PostgreSQL: crosstab возвращает одну строку

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть таблица заголовков:

```
|ID    | Название|
------------------
|0-21a | Материал|
|3-43c | Формат  |
```

Есть таблица значений:

```
|ID    | ID заголовка| Значение |
---------------------------------
|ps12 | 0-21a        | железо   |
|cy45 | 3-43c        | 56*31*23 |
```

Мне нужно вывести таблицу (crosstab):

```
|Материал | Формат  |
---------------------
|железо   | 56*31*23|
```

Делаю следующим образом:

```
select *
from crosstab(
    'select 1, a."Название", b."Значение"
    from a
    inner join b on a."ID"=b."ID заголовка"')
as t ("RowId" int, "Name" text, "Value" text)
```

RowId мне не нужен, но без него ("select 1") не работает, ругает:

```
The provided SQL must return 3 columns: rowid, category, and values.
```

В итоге этот запрос заработал, но вернул всего одну строку. Если запустить чисто скрипт:

```
select a."Название", b."Значение"
    from a
    inner join b on a."ID"=b."ID заголовка"
```

Выведет более 1000 записей. 
Подскажите, почему в моем запросе показывает только одну строку. Документацию читала (недоступно описано), по примерам тоже делала - ничего не выходит.
Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: *без него ("select 1") не работает* Вместо единицы поставьте там a."ID" - серверу надо же знать, по какому значению кросстабить? А с единицей у всех записей получается одна категория - потому и одна запись. *RowId мне не нужен* Уберите этот запрос в WITH, и снаружи оставьте только нужные поля.

Comment: @Akina только теперь поняла, зачем этот rowId. Большое спасибо. Ранее указывала ID, но неправильно указала тип данных - выходила соответствующая ошибка. Про WITH отдельное спасибо)